# How to pull a commit from a different relation chain in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Say I have the following two independent relation chains, how can I fulfill the two following scenarios:

**Relation chain 1:**
Commit A
Commit B

**Relation chain 2:**
Commit C

*First scenario*
How can I merge the changes from Commit A into Commit C and include the changes as part of the same commit? If I use the pull command from Gerrit it creates a merge commit rather than just adding the changes to staging.

*Second scenario*
How can I merge Commit C into Commit A during an interactive rebase? Again, using the Gerrit pull command results in a merge commit and I can't add the files to the rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first and second scenarios, use the "Cherry Pick" command instead of the "Pull" one.

If you don't want to create a new commit, add the "--no-commit" option to the "git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD" command and, after that, commit manually using the "git commit --amend" command.

Comment: Will this not add a second commit after the first, ie resulting in CA for the first scenario? The result for both should be the same commit but just with the extra changes.

Comment: I added more details to the answer.